# Boostrap popovers in Knockout foreach binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, foreach

I have a segment of HTML code that is bound to a knockout foreach loop. Inside of this segment, I have a glyphicon that I want to use to trigger a popover with some custom settings that the user can adjust. Here is the segment of code:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" data-bind="foreach: items">
  <li>
    <div>
      <a data-bind="attr:{id: itemId}" role="button" data-toggle="popover" title="Config Options" data-content="test content" data-placement="auto right">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I can manually put multiple of these glyphicon anchors in the code outside of the foreach loop and the popovers work just fine. They just don't work inside of a knockout foreach binding...

Does anybody know what I need to do to make the popovers work for items contained in a knockout foreach loop? Any suggestions or pointers on what I may be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE 1:

So after reviewing Buzinas answer and looking into the issue further, it turns out the issue appears to be with the fact that `items` is a `ko.observableArray` that is initialized empty. This array is populated based on user selections. When I add items to the array by default upon initialization, those popovers work. The only ones that don't work are the ones that are added on the fly by users. Any thoughts on this would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how it's working for you when not using KO, since the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) says:

> #### Opt-in functionality
>
> For performance reasons, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt-in,
>   meaning you must initialize them yourself.
>
> One way to initialize all popovers on a page would be to select them
>   by their data-toggle attribute:
>
> ```
> $(function () {
>    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
>  });
> ```

Then, I've tried to do that combining with KO, and everything worked fine:

```js
function AppViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.items = ko.observableArray([
    { itemId: 'id1' },
    { itemId: 'id2' },
    { itemId: 'id3' }
  ]);
  
  self.add = function() {
    self.items.push({ itemId: 'id' + self.items.length });
  }
}

ko.bindingHandlers.popover = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
      $(element).popover();
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

```css
li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav" data-bind="foreach: items">
  <li>
    <div>
      <a data-bind="attr:{id: itemId}, popover" role="button" data-toggle="popover" title="Config Options" data-content="test content" data-placement="auto right">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<button data-bind="click: add">Add</button>
```

#### Update

Since you have problems only when you need to add new items, you can create a [Custom Binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html), and I created one named `popover` for you:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.popover = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
      $(element).popover();
    }
};
```

And then, you can use it like this:

```
<a data-bind="popover">My anchor</a>
```

Comment: Just as a quick comment, yes, I did do the opt-in functionality part. I neglected to mention that in the original question. Sorry. I will continue to look over the rest of your answer and get back to you. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Ok so the issue with my code is that "items" is a ko.observableArray that is empty upon page initialization. "items" is populated based on user selections. When I add items by default, those popovers work. Any items added through user input don't work. Any ideas regarding that?

Comment: just a thought: it would be better to initialize the `.popover()` in a custom binding.  You can then pass observable properties to the popover and have it clean up properly when disposed.

Comment: @Buzinas Awesome!! This worked perfectly! Lesson learned: learn more about custom knockout bindings!! LOL! Thanks again!

Comment: @Milimetric Also, thank you for suggesting the custom bindings!

Comment: Here's an example for something similar but from a different library (semantic ui): https://github.com/wikimedia/analytics-dashiki/blob/master/src/app/ko-extensions/global-bindings.js#L85.  Notice the hook that destroys the popup if the dom node is disposed.  This is a nice example of modular design that makes it easy for others to use your code.